# Setting ListView Property FocusedItem to "Nothing" in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, listview

This Sub is supposed to remove the row of data (Items and subItems) at the "Selected/Focused" *ListView* index. It works but, after the selected row is removed, the Focus remains on the index of the row that was just Deleted.

Now the curent focused index contains a new row of data. I need "*ListView1.FocusedItem*" to reset to "*Nothing*" in order to make the User manualy select a row in the listView before the "Remove" button will remove anything.

As it is now, after the first row is selected and removed, you can just keep clicking the *"Remove"* button and it will keep deleting rows until the ListView is empty.

```
    Private Sub btn_Remove_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Remove.Click

        If IsNothing(Me.ListView1.FocusedItem) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please select an Item from the grocery list to be removed.")
        ElseIf ListView1.SelectedItems.Count <= 0 Then
            Me.ListView1.Items.RemoveAt(Me.ListView1.FocusedItem.Index)
            ' Need ListView1.FocusedItem to reset to "Nothing" here <<--------------------
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("There are no Items on the grocery list to be removed.")
        End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting *"**ListView1.FocusedItem.Focused**"* to *"**False**"* seems to have fixed my issue. I added an if statment containing "***ListView1.FocusedItem.Focused = False***". Now, when the Remove button is clicked and there has not been a manual selection of an Item in the ListView, "***Me.ListView1.FocusedItem***" IsNothing. Here is the working code:

```
   Private Sub btn_Remove_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Remove.Click

    If IsNothing(Me.ListView1.FocusedItem) Then
        MessageBox.Show("There are no Items selected to be removed from the grocery list.")

    ElseIf ListView1.SelectedItems.Count >= 0 Then
        Me.ListView1.Items.RemoveAt(Me.ListView1.FocusedItem.Index)

        If ListView1.Items.Count > 0 Then
            ListView1.FocusedItem.Focused = False
        End If

    Else
        MessageBox.Show("An Error has halted thid process")
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make nothing selected with:

```
ListView1.SelectedItems.Clear()
```

Comment: I tried to use "ListView1.SelectedItems.Clear()". I inserted it where my comment was and then I inserted it after the end of the "If" statment. Neither application set"Me.ListView1.FocusedItem" back to "Nothing". In each case, when I clicked the "Remove" button a second time, the new data (that took the index of the data I had just removed) was deleted. The If statment should show the "Please select an Item from the grocery list to be removed." MessageBox if the "ListView1.FocusedItem" Is "Nothing". That is why I am trying to set the focus to "Nothing"